# Java 'printf' formatting

Tags: java, printf

Is this correct printf usage in Java? 
I am trying to allocate 10 spaces for the principal which is double and have it display as 2 decimal places

```
System.out.printf("$ %10,.2f%n",principal);
```

Answer (score 0):

No this is wrong. It will show **Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '1'**

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are doing it right although the `,` will make you crash ;)

Just try `System.out.printf("$ %10.2f%n",principal);` and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

What think what you wanted is:

```
System.out.printf("%10.2f",var);
```

10 spaces wide, 2 positions after decimal (as above)

**TEST:**

```
System.out.printf("%10.2f",15.329);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
     15.33
```

Comment: @AndyJin If it solves you problem, accept the solution by clicking the hollow tick beside my answer. If you have more question, post in the comments.